# Pledge algorithm for maze solving robots

Tags: mobile-robot

i saw this maze, and tried to apply pledge algorithm on it. But i am not able to solve this maze using this algorithm. what am i missing?
i want to ask, what i am doing wrong?

PLEDGE ALGORITHM:
in both cases we don't get to exit.
[image]

you can read about these algorithms at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite see how you're doing the right-hand wall following. When I do it, this is what I get:

[image: Right hand wall following]

For the Pledge algorithm, it's working. It found an exit to the maze! It just so happens that the exit is the same as the start. If you want it to find the other exit, you'll have to block off the top exit after you enter the maze.